A question from a proof of an inequality in Sobolev space $W^{1,1}$
I try to understand the proof the lemma given at page 54 in Ladyzhenskaya et al (1968) - Linear and Quasilinear Elliptic Equations. Here it is a screenshot:

Here is what I did:
$$-u(x)=u(y)-u(x)=\int_{0}^{|x-y|}\dfrac{y-x}{|y-x|}\cdot\nabla u\left (x+t\dfrac{y-x}{|y-x|} \right )\ dt$$
Integrating on $\varepsilon_0\subset K_{\rho}$ (with respect to $y$) we get that:
$$-u(x)|\varepsilon_0|=\int_{\varepsilon_0} \int_{0}^{|x-y|}\dfrac{y-x}{|y-x|}\cdot\nabla u\left (x+t\dfrac{y-x}{|y-x|} \right )\ dt\ dy$$
Therefore:
$$|u(x)|\cdot |\varepsilon_0|\leq \int_{\varepsilon_0} \int_{0}^{|x-y|} \left |\nabla u\left (x+t\dfrac{y-x}{|y-x|} \right )\right |\ dt\ dy\leq$$
$$\leq\int_{K_r} |x-y|^{n-1}\int_{0}^{|x-y|}\dfrac{|\nabla u(\xi)|}{|x-\xi|^{n-1}}\ dt\ dy$$
Here I denoted $\xi=x+t\dfrac{y-x}{|y-x|}$. Thus $|x-\xi|=t\leq |x-y|$ which allows me to write that $\dfrac{1}{|x-y|^{n-1}}\leq\dfrac{1}{|x-\xi|^{n-1}}$. Here I am stucked...
I particularly don't understand the blue underlined parts of the estimates. What formulas/inequalities do the authors applied there? How this passages will look in a more modern way of writing?

The first blue are  spherical coordinates around $x$ and the second is similar.  Write $\xi=x+r\omega$, divide and multiply by $r^{n-1}$. The point is that the $\omega$ for $y$ and $\xi$ is the same. It is written in a better way in Lemma 7.16 of Gilbarg-Trudinger in a similar situation

In Lemma 7.16 of Gilbarg-Trudinger we have the following thing which I can't understand: $\displaystyle\int_{|x-y|<d} dy\int_{0}^{\infty} V(x+r\omega)\ dr=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{|\omega|=1}\int_{0}^d V(x+r\omega)\rho^{n-1}\ d\rho\ d\omega\ dr$. What do they applied here? Above it is said that $\omega=\dfrac{y-x}{|y-x|}$.

You have $y=x+\rho  \omega$ and then the LHS is $$\int_0^d \rho^{n-1} d\rho \int_{|\omega|=1} d\omega \int_0^\infty V(x+r\omega)\frac{r^{n-1}}{r^{n-1}}dr.$$ Now write $z=x+r\omega$; the integral in $d\omega dr$ equals $\int_{R^n} \frac{V(x+z)}{|z|^{n-1}} dz$ and that in $d\rho$ is $d^n/n$. Hope it is clear, now.
